# Modifying the parameters before passing them to NtWriteFile after hooking the SSDT

Tags: windows, kernel, driver, kernel-module, rootkit

I'm currently working on a lecture (and learning) about rootkits for Windows. I was able to hook the SSDT entry for NtWriteFile and display a simple message on WinDbg, but i'm now curious about what would be the best (and the safest) way of changing the parameters before passing them to the original function. In this example, i'm trying to change the buffer if it contains "My String". How could i swap the content of Buffer safely?

```
NTSTATUS ZwWriteFileHook(
IN HANDLE           FileHandle,
IN HANDLE           Event,
IN PIO_APC_ROUTINE  ApcRoutine,
IN PVOID            ApcContext,
IN PIO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock,
IN PVOID            Buffer,
IN ULONG            Length,
IN PLARGE_INTEGER   ByteOffset,
IN PULONG           Key
) 
{
    ... 
    if (!strncmp((PCHAR) Buffer, "My String", Length)) {
        // Modify parameters here
    }
    ntStatus = ((PZwWriteFile) zwWriteFileOld)(FileHandle, Event,
    ApcRoutine, ApcContext, IoStatusBlock, Buffer, Length, ByteOffset,
    Key);
    ...
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is an issue with accessing (reading/writing) UserMode pointers directly like that, you first want to probe the pointer for READ, if you write to it, you also need to to probe for WRITE using the kernel APIs [ProbeForRead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-probeforread) and [ProbeForWrite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-probeforwrite).

Second, I rather not write to the UserMode supplied buffer a modified value but allocate a new buffer and then free it afterwards, in my opinion it is the safest way.